# firebird database query with date time

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, datetime, firebird

I am trying to execute a query against a Firebird database using c# and don't have something quite right.  Note that I am executing these query against employee.fdb database example you get when installing Firebird.

The following works.

```
string query = @"SELECT EMPLOYEE.HIRE_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE HIRE_DATE > '02.01.1990, 03.04.05.000'";

using (FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(connectionString))
using (DataContext db = new DataContext(connection))
{
    List<employee> results = db.ExecuteQuery<employee>(query).ToList();
}
```

If I parameterize the date.

```
string query = @"SELECT EMPLOYEE.HIRE_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE HIRE_DATE > {0}";

using (FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(connectionString))
using (DataContext db = new DataContext(connection))
{
    List<employee> results = db.ExecuteQuery<employee>(query, "02.01.1990, 03.04.05.000").ToList();
}
```

I get a System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

And what I would really like to do is just use a DateTime object.

```
string query = @"SELECT EMPLOYEE.HIRE_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE HIRE_DATE > {0}";

using (FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(connectionString))
using (DataContext db = new DataContext(connection))
{
    DateTime a = new DateTime(1990, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    List<employee> results = db.ExecuteQuery<employee>(query, a).ToList();
}
```

But then I get a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Anybody know how I can use a DateTime as a parameter to the query?

Comment: What is the data type of `HIRE_DATE`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel HIRE_DATE has type Timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found an answer to my question.  I ended up doing a work around by doing the parameter substitution manually.

```
string query = @"SELECT EMPLOYEE.HIRE_DATE
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE HIRE_DATE > ";

string query = query + "'" + hireDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy, HH.mm.ss.fff") + "'";
```

And then used the other overload of ExecuteQuery

```
List<employee> results = db.ExecuteQuery<employee>(query).ToList();
```

I'm still interested in getting ExecuteQuery to do the substitution for me.  If anyone knows how, please post an answer.